# Excel 2013 stops working in sub

Tags: excel, error-handling, excel-2013, vba

I am using a VBA code, that highlights the border color of the active cell as the cell selector moves.

The code is

```
Private mOutline As Shape  
Private Const SelectedShapeName As String = "Selection Box"

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim SelectedShape As Shape
    Dim SelectedArea As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each SelectedShape In Sh.Shapes
        If SelectedShape.Name = SelectedShapeName Then
            SelectedShape.Delete
        End If
    Next SelectedShape

    For Each SelectedArea In Selection.Areas
        Set mOutline = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, SelectedArea.Left, SelectedArea.Top, SelectedArea.Width, SelectedArea.Height)
        With mOutline.OLEFormat.Object.ShapeRange
            .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Line.Transparency = 0
            .Line.Weight = 3
        End With
        mOutline.Name = SelectedShapeName
    Next SelectedArea
    On Error GoTo 0 End Sub
```

When I right-click on a column header in my worksheet, Excel suddenly stops working and exists.

Does anybody know what causes this error, and if so, how I can modify my code to avoid this?

Thank you.

Comment: Take out `On Error Resume Next` and step through in the debugger.  Which line causes the crash?

Comment: I get run-time error '1004' "The specific value is out of range" at the line `Set mOutline = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, SelectedArea.Left, SelectedArea.Top, SelectedArea.Width, SelectedArea.Height)`

Comment: When you say "right-click on a column header", are you referring to a *cell* or the column selection area?

Comment: The column selection area.

Comment: You should probably test if `Selection.Rows.Count = Rows.Count` as I can't see any benefit to putting a rectangle round the entire column, even if it did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is attempting to add a shape that is too tall for Excel to handle. When you right-click, it is selecting the entire column, so `SelectedArea.Top` is 0 and `SelectedArea.Height` is some absurdly large number (15728640 on my machine). That is causing `ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape` to fail.

Remove the `On Error Resume Next` line entirely.  You're ignoring the 1004 error instead of handling it.  Then the next line of code attempts to dereference an `OLEObject` that doesn't exist (which would be the second ignored error), and then attempts to assign a property to the null reference (which would be the third ignored error).  I'm not going to test to find out which one is bringing Excel down, but I would *guess* that either the 2nd or 3rd one is causing an access violation.

Either add proper error handling, or better, avoid the error by testing to see if you have a valid `Target`:

```
'Assuming you want to limit to one cell
If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Or Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```